# Где и как обрабатывать исключения при работе с классом File в Android проекте?

Tags: android, исключения

Я только учусь программированию на андроид, дошёл до темы исключений, и у меня появилось несколько вопросов касательно класса File:

1) **onCreate**. При запуске приложения я пытаюсь получить список файлов из директории либо создать её, если её нет. Если это не удалось, код не должен исполняться дальше. Правильно ли я написал catch блок? Мне кажется от стактрейса не будет проку.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainLay);

        File[] files;
        try {
            File directory = new File(way);
            files = directory.listFiles();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Create file or create folder error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
```

2) Метод **createFile** получает путь до файла и создаёт его по шаблону.

```
private File createFile(String path) throws IOException {
        String title = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = title + "_";
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".png", new File(path));
    }
```

Вызывается после пункта 1, то есть я предполагаю что к это моменту директория уже существует и с доступом всё ок. Поэтому я не ставлю try - catch для `File.createTempFile` перед return. Это правильно?

3) **onBindViewHolder**. Похожий вопрос, я не уверен что тут нужен try - catch блок, ведь к директории уже вроде как есть доступ.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final TestAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

        final File ins;
        try {
            ins = new File(path);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
```

4) **onBindViewHolder**, нужен ли try - catch блок для удаления файла?

```
File file = new File(path);
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

С остальными вопросами разобрался пока писал пост)

Upd 11.11.2018

Вопросы всё ещё актуальны. Почитав, я понял что обработки в случае 2,3 и 4 вроде как не нужны, потому что присутствует обработка 1 как высшая по стеку. Но вот с первым пунктом всё ещё остались непонятки.

Comment: Ты ловишь исключение в первом пункте и делаешь return  если оно исключение было.  Это значит, в случае исключения весь оставшийся код в функции oncreate() не выполнится. То есть если у тебя вся логика программы, все остальные инициации  находится в этой же функции ниже return, тогда все ок

Comment: А моё дополнение корректно? Если я ловлю исключение в `onCreate`, нужно ли мне ловить это же исключение в адаптере?

Comment: Если ты гарантируешь что состояние директории и ее отношение с приложением не изменится после запуска в течение всего времени, которое ты собираешься онБинВьюХолдить (работать со списком), то можешь не ловить